# Group by column and Spread values of another Column into other Columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have the current dataframe and I'm trying to group by the `Name` and spread the values of `weight` into the columns and count each time they occur.  Thanks!

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Name':['John','Paul','Darren','John','Darren'],
'Weight':['Average','Below Average','Above Average','Average','Above Average']})
```

Desired output:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use groupby and unstack:

```
    df = pd.DataFrame({'Name':['John','Paul','Darren','John','Darren'],
'Weight':['Average','Below Average','Above Average','Average','Above Average']})
df = df.groupby(['Name', 'Weight'])['Weight'].count().unstack(1).fillna(0).astype(int).reset_index()
df = df.rename_axis('', axis=1).set_index('Name')
df
Out[1]: 
        Above Average  Average  Below Average
Name                                         
Darren              2        0              0
John                0        2              0
Paul                0        0              1
```

Comment: use .fillna(0) at the end to get the desired result.

Comment: @adhg yes,  I also included `.reset_index()`. Thanks.

Comment: @DavidErickson What is "weight" in your result?  Is it not part of the column headers?

Comment: Weight is the index. With how unstack works and reset index works, that what it looks like. You can change the name of the index. If you send the file to excel with `to_csv` or `to_excel` and pass `index=False`, then that will be ignored.

Comment: Is it possible to completely reset the "Weight" index back to to default index?

Comment: @dko512 like this? Do this at the end. `df = df.rename_axis('', axis=1)` See updated answer.

Answer (score 3):

Try [pandas crosstab](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html) :

```
pd.crosstab(df.Name, df.Weight)

Weight  Above Average   Average Below Average
Name            
John           0           2        0
Paul           0           0        1
Darren         2           0        0
```

Comment: aaah... I will never forget about `pd.crosstab` again :) +1

Answer (score 1):

Use `get dummies` to achieve what you need here

```
pd.get_dummies(df.set_index('Name'), dummy_na=False,prefix=[None]).groupby('Name').sum()
 

         Above Average  Average  Below Average
Name                                         
Darren              2        0              0
John                0        2              0
Paul                0        0              1
```